# Isomorphism of Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $L/K$ be a Galois extension over the field $K$. Is it true that $$\text{Hom}_K(L,\text{Hom}_L(L,L)) \cong \text{Hom}_K(L,L)?$$

Any ideas to start me off would be great. Would it come down to showing that $L \cong \text{Hom}_L(L,L)$?

Comment: Yes, we have this $L$-isomorphism, which  *ipso facto* a $K$-isomorphism by restriction of scalars.

Comment: $\text{Hom}_L(L,L) = \{Id\}$ so what is the LHS supposed to mean (maybe you meant $\text{Hom}_{L\ vector space}(L,L) \cong L$, isomorphism of $L$-algebra, whereas on the RHS it is $Hom_{K \ algebra}(L,L)$ which only has a group structure)

Comment: @Liam In field theory $Hom_K(L,L)=Aut(L/K)$  is the set (group) of $K$-algebra homomorphisms $L\to L$.

Comment: @reuns Is this true? The elements on the right are isomorphisms, while the ones on the left are not necessarily.